# SQL Server - Need to obtain records before current year and month from date text fields

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that holds dates for each record in the form of text fields. I have three such fields (yyyy and mm and yyyymm). So as an example, I have a field that shows "201412" (it is a text data type without double quotes. In SQL Server I would like to query and pull only records that have a year and month less than the current year and month. So as of this writing on november 30, 2015, I want all records before November 2015. I would like to embed it in an Select statement. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? How about cast(YourColumn + '01' as date)? If at all possible you should stop storing date information in strings. It is painful to work with and validation is nearly impossible. You should always use the proper datatypes.

Comment: Its better if you present what you have done, in order to get better and answers.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively easy way is to use date arithmetic:

```
where yyyy * 12 + mm < year(getdate()) * 12 + month(getdate())
```

Actually, you can replace the `12` with `100` if you prefer.

Comment: Gordon, Thanks very much. It works well. But I forgot to mention that my month is fixed length. So August is stored as 08. I cannot change the system date here at work to an earlier month this year in order to test to see if it will still work when it is August and I'm looking for records earlier than 201508. Do you think it will still work throughout the year?

Comment: @PeteS . . . Actually, that doesn't change anything.  SQL Server will automatically convert it to an integer when used in arithmetic.